# Plugin onclick button activate other plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

I have some code that have a button in the backend page.

I want to click on the button and have it activate a plugin that's already in the plugin's directory.

Here's the code:

```
<?php


add_action('admin_menu', 'addons_plugin_setup_menu');

function addons_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Addons', 'Addons', 'manage_options', 'addons-plugin', 'addons_init' );
}

function addons_init(){
        ?>


        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                                        <h4>Addons</h4>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="testme()">Activate</button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </nav>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <?php
}

function testme() {
    activate_plugin( 'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php' );
    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        // Process Error
    }
}


?>
```

When I click the button I get "testme" is not defined

How can I get this to work?

**Updated to this:**

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'addons_plugin_setup_menu');

function addons_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Addons', 'Addons', 'manage_options', 'addons', 'addons_init' );
}

function addons_init(){
        ?>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
              $( '#activate_plugin' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var ajaxurl     = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
                  var security    = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "activate_plugin" ); ?>';
                  $.ajax( {
                      url: ajaxurl,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      type: 'POST',
                      delay: 150,
                      data :'action=activate_plugin&security='+security,
                      success: function( data ) {
                          console.log( data + ', Plugin Activated!' );
                      },
                  } );
              } );
          } );
        </script>


        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                                        <h4>Addons</h4>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <button id="activate_plugin" class="btn btn-success">Activate</button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </nav>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    function activate_plugin_ajax_callback() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'activate_plugin', 'security' );
        activate_plugin( 'ttt/index.php' );
        if( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            // Process Error
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_activate_plugin', 'activate_plugin_ajax_callback' );
?>

        <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't execute a PHP function using `onclick`.  I think what you'd need to do is use AJAX to call the `testme()` function.  I've never even attempted it before but if you do want to try it this way try `onclick="<?php testme(); ?>"` but I'm like 99.99% certain the won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a couple of things.  First I added an ID to the HTML button just to make life a bit easier in case there end up being multiple buttons with the same classes doing different things.

Then I wrote a quick and simple little AJAX function - doesn't really need to pass much data, it just needs to verify itself to WP so that WP knows it's allowed to execute the function.

Then I wrote another function in php that basically activates the plugin.

```
<!-- //ADDED AN ID TO THE BUTTON -->
<button id="activate_plugin" class="btn btn-success">Activate</button>

<!-- //THE AJAX -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $( '#activate_plugin' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ajaxurl     = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
        var security    = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "activate_plugin" ); ?>';
        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            delay: 150,
            data :'action=activate_plugin&security='+security,
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data + ', Plugin Activated!' );
            },
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>

<!-- //THE AJAX CALLBACK -->
<?php
    function activate_plugin_ajax_callback() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'activate_plugin', 'security' );
        activate_plugin( 'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php' );
        if( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            // Process Error
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_activate_plugin', 'activate_plugin_ajax_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_activate_plugin', 'activate_plugin_ajax_callback' );
?>
```

There's a lot of other neat little things you can do, like IF the plugin is already active, then don't even display the button.

```
<?php if( is_plugin_inactive( 'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php' ) ) : ?>
<button id="activate_plugin" class="btn btn-success" onclick="testme()">Activate</button>
<?php else : ?>
<span class="activated-note">The XXX Plugin is installed and activated.</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could also set your AJAX success to remove the button and add the note by replacing the `success` portion of your AJAX with:

```
success: function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
    alert( 'Plugin Activated!' );
    $( '#activate_plugin' ).toggle();
    $( '.navbar-header' ).append( '<span class="activated-note">The XXX Plugin is installed and activated.</span>' );
},
```

Comment: Ok, I've added a code update to the questions...see code below:  "Updated to this" in the question. Basically nothing happens when I click the buton and no errors either...any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn’t add jQuery, it’s already added in the admin.   Can you check your developer console and when you click the button see what “admin-ajax.php” has in it’s Headers?

Comment: This is what it's returning: Request URL:http://localhost:8888/wptest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Request method:POST
Remote address:[::1]:8888
Status code:
400
Version:HTTP/1.1

Comment: That means that, for some reason, WP isn't allowing you to run AJAX.  Not sure what it could be - really hard to tell without being able to test.  Can you scroll down the headers and see that your `action` and `security` are being sent and what they are?

Comment: action is: activate_plugin and security says: 5986dc8969

Comment: A couple of notes, I've added a second `add_action()` that applies `wp_ajax_nopriv_` add that in and see if it helps.  Also, and I'm not actually sure if this is a rule or not, but it's how I learned to do it and how every example out there showed me how to do it, but I always have the HTML/jQuery/AJAX in one file and then the PHP AJAX Callback/Action in another file.  (I actually don't see WHY it would be necessary, but it's how I've always been done it. I have all my callbacks in one file and include that at the bottom of my functions.php.) Did you remove the jQuery inclusion?

Comment: OK, I added the new action and removed the jquery but still the same 400 error

Comment: I've just realize that "function activate_plugin_ajax_callback()" is never reached

Comment: That’s what I was thinking.  Try putting the first part of your code in one file and the ‘activate_plugin_ajax_callback()’ in another and then include both files using require_once() in your main plugin file.

Comment: Here's how I do it.  In the main plugin file, I only include other files (keeps the code clean and digestible) and then I place the separate parts I'm including into an `/inc/` subdirectory, like this: `require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/add_plugin_buttons.php' );` & `require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/add_plugin_ajax_callback.php' );`  You'll need to make sure this matches what you've called your files and that the directory name matches as well.